# Cant find network driver for RTL8723de

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

I recently installed Ubuntu however I ran into a problem. I can’t seem to find the network driver and I can’t connect to the WiFi. Is there possibly a way to fix this?

Comment: Start here https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25463958/ I used the commands to write this file.

Comment: Thanks for the output. The device you have seems to be RTL8723de. According to [this forum thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2367405) it is not supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is an unofficial native Linux driver now available here: https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de