# "RTL8723DE" Wireless Card not working in HP-15bs015dx laptop

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, hp, realtek-wireless

I have a new HP-15bs015dx laptop which has Realtek RTL8723DE Wireless network card. I dual booted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.1 with 4.4.0-31-generic kernel. Now, I am unable to connect to internet in Ubuntu.

I wonder if there is any driver firmware for DE series after looking at this page which mentions firmware upto 8723BE only.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsWirelessNetworkCardsRealTek

If it is not the case, how can I setup my WLAN card working?Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: a quick search suggest that there is not yet a linux driver for the DE card

Comment: ...same as this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/952495/cant-find-network-driver#comment1518004_952495

Comment: Solution here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2367405&page=3&p=13723723#post13723723 You need the instruction for kernels lower than 4.10

Comment: You should promote your comment to an answer, or Rusting Gold should update his! :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no driver available as of now for RTL8723DE adapter. https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/267

Answer (score 0):

I too have this HP laptop. The WiFi driver for Linux is indeed not available currently since Realtek has not released it. [Larry Finger](https://github.com/lwfinger) says that the driver should be released [by the end of this year](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/267).

Also [NDISwrapper](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper) works only with Windows XP drivers and this network card only has drivers for Windows 7 and up.

So you have three options left:

1. Wait till Realtek releases the driver.
2. Keep nagging Realtek for the driver.
3. Contribute to the driver yourself. (Trust me, it's not that hard :)